# Why are questions with Ignored Tags listed on the newest question tab?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I have listed a few tags to be ignored in my profile. The newest questions tagged with ignored tags are still listed and grayed out. I suppose it would be better to exclude such questions instead of graying them out. This would free up some space and require less scrolling to navigate the newest questions of interest.

<sub>*Apologies if this does not make sense, as it's my first post on meta.*</sub>

Comment: They do so only, if there's another tag used for those questions that appears in your favorite tags list, or you don't use a tag filter at the frontpage at all.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ, I suppose you are referring to the list of questions that appear under the **interesting**, when you click on the stackoverflow home link, while i was referring to the list of questions under the **newest** tab that is displayed when you click the Questions link.

Comment: I was referring to the newest tab, but showing (tag) filtered results.